# Log4net to database not working

Tags: .net, t-sql, logging, log4net

I've got problem logging to the DB via log4net.

- User has permission to insert into database
- Same insert statement does work in Management Studio
- log4net does log to file but not to DB
- Connection string is correct (same in other applications)

Got the following configuration:

```
<log4net debug="true">
    <appender name="FileAppender" type="log4net.Appender.FileAppender">
        <file type="log4net.Util.PatternString" value="Logs\JallaJalla (%date{yyyyMMdd HHmmss}).log" />
        <appendToFile value="true" />
        <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
            <conversionPattern value="%date %logger %-5level - %message%newline" />
        </layout>
    </appender>

    <appender name="ADONetAppender" type="log4net.Appender.AdoNetAppender">
        <threshold value="DEBUG"/>
        <bufferSize value="1" />
        <connectionType value="System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection, System.Data, Version=1.0.3300.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" />
        <connectionString value="Data Source=xxx;Initial Catalog=xxx;User Id=xxx;Password=xxx;" />
        <commandText value="INSERT INTO [log].[tLogTable] ([Message],[Level]) VALUES (@message, @log_level)" />

        <parameter>
            <parameterName value="@message" />
            <dbType value="String" />
            <size value="4000" />
            <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
                <conversionPattern value="%message" />
            </layout>
        </parameter>

        <parameter>
            <parameterName value="@log_level" />
            <dbType value="String" />
            <size value="50" />
            <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
                <conversionPattern value="%level" />
            </layout>
        </parameter>

    </appender>

    <logger name="ADONetAppender">
        <level value="ALL" />
        <appender-ref ref="ADONetAppender" />
    </logger>

    <logger name="FileLogger">
        <level value="ALL" />
        <appender-ref ref="FileAppender" />
    </logger>
</log4net>
```

The two columns in the DB are:

- Message varchar(max) not null
- Level varchar(50) not null

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem myself...

```
private static readonly ILog Logger = LogManager.GetLogger( "FileLogger" );
```

The name of the logger was set to "FileLogger"
So by adding

```
<appender-ref ref="ADONetAppender" />
```

inside

```
<logger name="FileLogger">
    <level value="ALL" />
    <appender-ref ref="FileAppender" />
    <appender-ref ref="ADONetAppender" /> 
</logger>
```

solved the problem!

Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 0):

I guess you forgot to add the following to you assamblies which you want enable logging:

```
[assembly: log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator()]
```

or from code:

```
log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator.Configure();
```